# O que significa "na véspera"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, significado-em-contexto

O que significa **na véspera**?
Procurando na internet parece que significa como **dia anterior**! Pode ser isso?

Comment: Sim, está correto. Se a palavra pode ser encontrada em múltiplos dicionários e as acepções coincidem, pode assergurar-se de que elas estão certas.

Comment: vou dar um voto para a tua pergunta. Mesmo sendo fácil encontrar o significado na internet, me sensibilizei da mesma forma quando eu estou aprendendo uma outra lingua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na véspera = Dia imediatamente anterior àquele de que se trata

Nas vésperas = Os dias que antecedem mais proximamente um fato ou acontecimento ex. O Stalin andava cansado nas vésperas da invasão de quatro milhoēs de soldados alemaēs na grande operação militar de que viemos a saber de 'Barbarossa.'

Answer (score 2):

segundo o dicionáro [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/v%C3%A9spera)

> vés·pe·ra  (latim vespera, -ae, a tarde) substantivo feminino
>
> 1. Dia que antecede imediatamente a outro determinado.
> 2. [Antigo]  A tarde.
>
> vésperas substantivo feminino plural
> 3. Dias que mais proximamente antecedem qualquer dia ou .fato.
>
> 4. [Liturgia católica]  Horas que se rezam no ofício da tarde.

Respondendo a tua pergunta. Sim, é o dia anterior ao referido.